# Swift : animator() causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: animation, swift

I've noticed some strange behaviour with implicit animation under OS X 10.10 since beta 5.
Calling animation proxy will sometimes cause app to crash. I set up a really simple custom view. Here's the full code :

```
import Cocoa
import QuartzCore

class AnimatedView: NSView {

    var firstColor: NSColor = NSColor.blackColor() {
        didSet {
           self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    var secondColor: NSColor = NSColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)

        let outerRect = self.bounds
        let halfW = outerRect.width / 4.0
        let halfH = outerRect.height / 4.0
        var innerRect = outerRect
        innerRect.inset(dx: halfW, dy: halfH)
        self.firstColor.set()
        NSRectFill(outerRect)
        self.secondColor.set()
        NSRectFill(innerRect)
    }

    override func animationForKey(key: String!) -> AnyObject! {
        switch key {
        case "firstColor", "secondColor" :
            return CABasicAnimation()
        default :
            return super.animationForKey(key)
        }
    }
}
```

If I try to animate NSView's ans ancestor's properties everything work like a charm. Such as :

```
animView.animator().frame = someFrame
```

If I try to animate AnimatedView's property such as firstColor or secondColor :

```
animView.animator().firstColor = someColor
animView.animator().secondColor = someOtherColor
```

It crashes with various error code (no change made in code between tries) :

- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_386_GPFLT)
- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x...)
- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x...) (address is often 0x0)

No object is Nil (I've checked twice).

Sometimes it complains about __CFString, sometimes it just crashes without change in code but it never works...

I think it's some sort of bug but I have to be sure before reporting, perhaps I forgot something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Re-read release notes, noticed dynamic keyword, tested it, works !
So if you want to animate custom properties you have to use dynamic keyword in property declaration :

```
dynamic var firstColor: NSColor = NSColor.blackColor() {
    didSet {
        self.needsDisplay = true
    }
}

dynamic var secondColor: NSColor = NSColor.whiteColor() {
    didSet {
        self.needsDisplay = true
    }
}
```

I don't know why it worked prior to beta 5 and I don't know if it is a temporary workaround or if it is the *normal* way to use it but it works which is nice.

Comment: Update: for Swift 4 the properties must also be marked with the `@objc` attribute, i.e. `@objc dynamic var firstColor ...`.